# How to schedule gap between shutdown and bringing up a AIX 6.1 host ?

Tags: aix, shutdown

I wan to shutdown an AIX 6.1 server immediately and then bring it up after 4 hours automatically ? Is that possible with shutdown command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible via shutdown command directly on the server/LPAR. Because if the server is powered off, how should shutdown start it up again? You could only do this from an HMC with a small script, which triggers [`chsysstate` command](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/POWER7/p7edm/chsysstate.html) with e.g. the `-o osshutdown --immediate` action (same as `shutdown -Fh` on the server) to shutdown the server/LPAR, and 4 hours later then start it up again via the `chsysstate -o on` operation.

Only other alternative would be to do a normal reboot on the server, but let some script be run once during only the next bootup for e.g. 4 hours via e.g. `sleep 1440` and then continue normal boot.

Could you elaborate on the reason for doing that as you currently require?

Comment: Yes doing from HMC would be the only option. SAN team is making storage changes and require host to be down precisely for 4 hours. I will try that sleep script on out test host. Thanks

Comment: The sleep script in the second approach would mean the server is online the whole time - although for 4 hours basically only in single-user mode, but still online and logged in to the SAN, if rootvg consists of SAN disks.

You want to go for `chsysstate -o osshutdown / sleep 1440 / chssysstate -o on` on HMC, just for clarity ...